# All possible chars for representing a number as a String, Integer.java

Tags: java, integer, hex

In Integer.java, there is the following piece of code:

```
/**
 * All possible chars for representing a number as a String
 */
final static char[] digits = {
    '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
    '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
    'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
    'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
    'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
    'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
};
```

I thought all the digits/characters you would ever need are in the range 0-9 and letters A to F. Letters (A,B,C,D,E and F) would be used only when the numbers are represented in base 16 (hexadecimal).

Why does the Javadoc say "All possible chars" ? Are the letters from G to Z actually used ? I would think that they could be used if the base, we represent the numbers in, is greater than 16.

Comment: toString(), getChars() and toUnsignedString() method of Integer class uses this array to store char value corresponding to integer index value . and as mentioned below answers explain this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `toString` method supports arbitrary bases (like 20) up to `MAX_RADIX` which is defined as `36`

Answer (score 6):

["Base36: Uses in practice"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36#Uses_in_practice) explains some common use cases.

> - The Remote Imaging Protocol for bulletin board systems used base 36 notation for transmitting coordinates in a compact form.
> - Many URL redirection systems like TinyURL or SnipURL/Snipr also use base 36 integers as compact alphanumeric identifiers.
> - Geohash-36, a coordinate encoding algorithm, uses radix 36 but uses a mixture of lowercase and uppercase alphabet characters in order to avoid vowels, vowel-looking numbers, and other character confusion.
> - Various systems such as RickDate use base 36 as a compact representation of Gregorian dates in file names, using one digit each for the day and the month.
> - [and many more]

Protocol designers sometimes need a compact, ASCII alphanumeric, case-insensitive scheme for encoding integers.  Base36 fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

it supports the radix base up to 36 while converting integer to string representation.

Both MAX and MIN radix are specified in Character class as

```
public static final int MIN_RADIX = 2;
public static final int MAX_RADIX = 36;
```

try something like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 36; i++) {
            System.out.println("Radix = "+i+" -- " + Integer.toString(123, i));
        }
```

Output:

```
Radix = 2 -- 1111011
Radix = 3 -- 11120
Radix = 4 -- 1323
Radix = 5 -- 443
Radix = 6 -- 323
Radix = 7 -- 234
Radix = 8 -- 173
Radix = 9 -- 146
Radix = 10 -- 123
Radix = 11 -- 102
Radix = 12 -- a3
Radix = 13 -- 96
Radix = 14 -- 8b
Radix = 15 -- 83
Radix = 16 -- 7b
Radix = 17 -- 74
Radix = 18 -- 6f
Radix = 19 -- 69
Radix = 20 -- 63
Radix = 21 -- 5i
Radix = 22 -- 5d
Radix = 23 -- 58
Radix = 24 -- 53
Radix = 25 -- 4n
Radix = 26 -- 4j
Radix = 27 -- 4f
Radix = 28 -- 4b
Radix = 29 -- 47
Radix = 30 -- 43
Radix = 31 -- 3u
Radix = 32 -- 3r
Radix = 33 -- 3o
Radix = 34 -- 3l
Radix = 35 -- 3i
Radix = 36 -- 3f
```